# Compare the associative array values and return the different values

Tags: php, arrays

I have an associative array below like this:

```
<?php 
    $first = array(
        array('lastexam' => '170220', 'nextexam' => '170220', 'phone' => '170220', 'fax' => '170220'),
        array('lastexam' => '170220', 'nextexam' => '170220', 'phone' => '170220', 'fax' => '170220'),
        array('lastexam' => '170221', 'nextexam' => '170220', 'phone' => '170224', 'fax' => '170220'),
        array('lastexam' => '170221', 'nextexam' => '170226', 'phone' => '170220', 'fax' => '170220'),
        array('lastexam' => '170222', 'nextexam' => '170220', 'phone' => '170225', 'fax' => '170220')
    ); 
?>
```

I need to compare  the values `$first[0]` to `$first[1]`, `$first[1]` to `$first[2]`, `$first[2]` to `$first[3]`, and `$first[3]` to `$first[4]`. I need to get result as below:

For example:

```
<?php
array
(
  [2] => array
  (
     [lastexam] => 170221,
     [phone] => 170224,
  ),
  [3] => array
  (
     [nextexam] => 170226,
     [phone] => 170220,
  ),
  [4] => array
  (
     [lastexam] => 170222,
     [phone] => 170225,
  )
);
?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this would solve your problem

```
<?php 
    $first = array(
        array('lastexam' => '170220', 'nextexam' => '170220', 'phone' => '170220', 'fax' => '170220'),
        array('lastexam' => '170220', 'nextexam' => '170220', 'phone' => '170220', 'fax' => '170220'),
        array('lastexam' => '170221', 'nextexam' => '170220', 'phone' => '170224', 'fax' => '170220'),
        array('lastexam' => '170221', 'nextexam' => '170226', 'phone' => '170220', 'fax' => '170220'),
        array('lastexam' => '170222', 'nextexam' => '170220', 'phone' => '170225', 'fax' => '170220')
        );

    $pre = array();
    $cur = array();
    $tmp = array();
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($first); echo '</pre>';
    foreach($first as $key => $val) {
        foreach ($val as $key1 => $val1) {
            $cur[$key1] = $val1;
            if (isset($pre[$key1]) && $pre[$key1] !== $cur[$key1]) {
                $tmp[$key][$key1] = $val1;
            }
            $pre[$key1] = $val1;
        }
    }
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($tmp); echo '</pre>';
    ?>
```

if so please like or else comment below

Answer (score 1):

I find it a lot cleaner to use `array_diff` as suggested by Brad Kent in the comments.

```
$result = [];
for ($i = count($first)-1; $i >= 1; $i--) {
    $diff = array_diff($first[$i], $first[$i-1]);
    if (!empty($diff))
        $result[$i] = $diff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this a little bit what you are searching for?

```
     $first = array(
        array('lastexam' => '170220', 'nextexam' => '170220', 'phone' => '170220', 'fax' => '170220'),
        array('lastexam' => '170220', 'nextexam' => '170220', 'phone' => '170220', 'fax' => '170220'),
        array('lastexam' => '170221', 'nextexam' => '170220', 'phone' => '170224', 'fax' => '170220')
        ); 


    if((array_values($first)[0]['lastexam']) == (array_values($first)[1]['lastexam'])){

        var_dump(array_values($first)[2]['lastexam']);
        var_dump(array_values($first)[2]['phone']);

    } else {
        //
        echo "whatever..." ;
        //
    }
```

?? not perfect yet because I did not grasp the total picture you want to achieve. But with this if statement you can atleast compare what you wanted to compare. Good Luck!.